# I try to use trigger for auto change field values when this field values = 0 and get MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, database

```
+------------+------------------+
| AMPHUR_NAME| AMPHUR_NAME_ENG  |
+------------+------------------+
| 1235855    | test12345        |
| 0          | zero             |  << I Want it.
+------------+------------------+
```

I Want update when AMPHUR_NAME = 0 and auto change AMPHUR_NAME_ENG = zero.
I try to use trigger in phpmyadmin.

I get this error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'amphur' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

From the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test` AFTER UPDATE ON `amphur`
FOR EACH ROW 
IF new.AMPHUR_NAME = 0
THEN
           UPDATE amphur SET amphur.AMPHUR_NAME_ENG = 'zero';
END IF
```

Comment: Why do use a trigger?

Comment: @Strawberry i want auto check and update value when this field = 0

Comment: OK. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the same table when the table is used in a trigger.

You need to update the NEW.AMPHUR_NAME_ENG. 
So your trigger code should be something like this.

**Query**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test` AFTER UPDATE ON `amphur`
FOR EACH ROW 
IF NEW.AMPHUR_NAME = 0
THEN
   SET NEW.AMPHUR_NAME_ENG = 'zero';
END IF
```